# How to get exact position of a panel or picturebox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating C# application where I have a text box and a panel on the main form. I want to get the exact position of the panel relative to the screen's top-left corner (0,0). When I call `this.Left` and `this.Top` at the form it gives me the correct coordinates, but when I call `panel.Location.X` and `panel.Location.Y` it results in coordinates relative to the form, which is constant no matter where my form is located on the screen.

I want to get the top and left coordinates of a panel not relative to the form but relative to the screen, assuming top & left of the screen is (0,0).

How can I get the absolute position of my panel?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Control.PointToScreen Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get location relative to screen:

```
Point location = PointToScreen(panel.Location);
```

Comment: This assumes the panel is directly contained by the form.  For it to work regardless of the container, you can use the panel itself and pass (0, 0): `Point location = panel.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));`